# Add UIButton above new library ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have imported a third party library into my project which I am calling it's main ViewController from the appDelegate of my original project.  I am trying to add a backButton (without changing the code of the third party library).

I am presenting the VC in my AppDelegate with the following

```
ABSViewController *abs = [[ABViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:abs
                                                 animated:NO
                                               completion:nil];
```

I am then trying to add my UIButton programatically with the below but it won't appear at the front even with calling 'bringSubViewToFront'

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
backButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

[abs.view addSubview:backButton];
[abs.view bringSubviewToFront:backButton];
```

I can see the button is created before the presentViewController animation completes but it is set behind the ABSViewController (library ViewController)

Comment: where do you add the button after calling `presentViewController` ??

Comment: How is this view presented? If you are using navigation controller and pushing this VC, than you can set `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [UIBarButton alloc] init ...]` and you will get this back button.

Comment: And for if presenting VC than you can also set `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelPicker)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the button in the completion handler of `presentViewController`

```
ABSViewController *abs = [[ABViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    backButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    [abs.view addSubview:backButton];
    [abs.view bringSubviewToFront:backButton];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem, the button was being created before the view.